# Golang. Несколько сообщений в одном TCP соединении

Tags: golang, tcp

Всем привет. Возможно ли в одном tcp соединении отправить несколько сообщений и обработать ответы по ним?

```
connection, _ := net.Dial("tcp",  net.JoinHostPort("host", "port"))
_, _ := connection.Write([]byte("message1" + "\r\n"))
// чтение ответа
_, _ := connection.Write([]byte("message2" + "\r\n"))
// чтение ответа
```

Answer (score 1):

Да, можно. Явных ограничений сам протокол TCP не накладывает. Главное аккуратно проверяйте коды ошибок.

Comment: Но есть важное условие: *If the returned error is nil, the Response will contain a non-nil Body which the user is expected to close. If the Body is not both read to EOF and closed, the Client's underlying RoundTripper (typically Transport) may not be able to re-use a persistent TCP connection to the server for a subsequent "keep-alive" request.* https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client.Do

Comment: мне кажется, Вы скопировали не с того документа. Http может (и обычно так и делает) использовать tcp, но вот наоборот - это уже немного другая история

Comment: Да, справка про http, но по-моему, это будет справедливо и для tcp (не проверял).

Comment: нет, не будет. Там описывается применимые к http вещи.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете с сырым TCP-сокетом делать что угодно. Варианты доставки нескольких сообщений:

1. последовательно, одно за другим
2. одной посылкой -- в составе структуры (например, JSON)

Надо помнить о том, что сообщения могут иметь разные приоритеты. Например, телеметрия (короткое сообщение, минимальный интервал времени), пересылка фотографии (минимальные накладные расходы).

Comment: приоритеты в tcp? это об OOB или просто sctp?

Comment: Это про политику: что вам важнее -- либо сделать быстро, либо надёжно, либо целиком.

Comment: Вы прям как политик отвечаете - вроде и связано, но абсолютно бессмысленно